# Can I get Full size photo published on a wall of an user?

Tags: facebook

I've tried with Graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=BillGates%2Fposts

but it returns (under the tag `picture`) a small size photo. How can I get the link of that photo, at bigger size? Can I?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any connections for the Posts that you are fetching to directly get the bigger photo sizes according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.

But you can fetch the Photo object itself from the 'object_id' of the posts with type 'photo' and then get all the image sizes from there: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10151450339221961

It should then have an images attribute of all the available image sizes of the photo:

```
"images": [
{
  "height": 393, 
  "width": 700, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_n.jpg"
}, 
{
  "height": 393, 
  "width": 700, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_n.jpg"
}, 
{
  "height": 336, 
  "width": 600, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s600x600/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_n.jpg"
}, 
{
  "height": 269, 
  "width": 480, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s480x480/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_n.jpg"
}, 
{
  "height": 179, 
  "width": 320, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s320x320/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_n.jpg"
}, 
{
  "height": 101, 
  "width": 180, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_a.jpg"
}, 
{
  "height": 72, 
  "width": 130, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_s.jpg"
}, 
{
  "height": 72, 
  "width": 130, 
  "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s75x225/417933_10151450339221961_1121449374_s.jpg"
}
```

]

Comment: But how can I know which I should take? There is no a "big/medium/small" tag, I can't choose it randomly :(

Comment: Yeah, there's no easy way to get that since I think that there's all sorts of sizes and standards for the photos. You're best best is to use the photo at index 0 to get the largest. They usually are ordered from largest to smallest. Otherwise, you'll have to go by the 'height' and 'width' attributes and go with whichever works best for you.